# Theoretically hashing something 2^128 times with the MD5 algrithm

Tags: math, hash, md5, theory

This is a purely hypothetical question, but if you were to start with 128 bits, and then hash them 2^128 times, say with the MD5 algorithm, would you eventually come back to your original bits? Would all possible combinations have been used? And if not, are there certain nubers that "hash back to themselves" faster than others?

I assume this is practically impossible to achieve (after looking at my calculators answer to 2^128...), and I'm pretty sure the answer would be different for different algorithms, but that doesn't stop one from theoretizing, does it?

So yeah, that's it, hope someone out there will have some more knowledge on this topic. Looking forward to seeing the answer(s), thanks in advance!

Edit:
To clarify: What interests me the most in this question is **if it will go through all possible bit combinations or if there rather are several smaller cycles**, tho any additional, relevant and interesting information is appreciated.

Comment: To me, if you have 128 bits then you only have 2^128 combinations/items in your set.  So at some point you will get a collision if you hash a value 2^128 times.

Comment: There obviously have to be some cycles, since there are a finite number of values. But not every number has to be a member of a cycle. It's probably something like Conway's Game of Life: there are some cyclical configurations, and other configurations that eventually fall into one of those.

Comment: Some hashes are destructive, some not.  Dunno about MD5.  With a destructive hash you'll never (well, hardly ever) cycle back, but will eventually "stabilize" on a small number of patterns.

Comment: This question is theoretical, not practical.

Comment: A permutation can be broken into a collection of cycles. MD5 when mapping 128 bits to 128 bits is not a permutation. Instead, this will look like a collection of cycles and "tails". If you iterate the hash 2^128 times you must end up on a cycle.

Comment: @Barmar my thoughts exactly, and ten the question is: are there multiple cycles or only one, containing all possible configurations? i'm guessing the first.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right, I meant in case anyone had actually tried ;)

Comment: @GregS Why don't you make an answer about it? Because I would have accepted that one.

Comment: @Ludwik: Because I think it is off-topic. You can actually get much better answers in math.stackexchange.com. Those guys are smaaaarrrttt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good cryptographic hash should have some, but not too many, cycles in it, that makes it much harder to create rainbow tables for it. This occurs in the MD5 - actually a problem with MD5 is that it's a bit to easy too find hash collisions for a given hash for the algorithm. This weakness makes it computationally feasible to inject malicious data in a file that is hashed with MD5 for verification.

I think you think there's some [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) property of the MD5, but this is not the case. The hash function will probably start to walk in circles quite soon, and it should.

There's also a very memory efficient way to find [MD5 cycles](http://stevekrenzel.com/articles/md5-cycles). Also have a look at [MD5CRK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5CRK).

If you really want a unique "hashing" of an 128-bit id, you should use an ordinary encryption algorithm, for instance with AES, of a particular number and a secret key. This gives you a "random", unique row of numbers form an increasing id, since you can always decrypt the information in a unique way, given the same key that was used to encrypt the data.

Comment: In your last paragraph, you misspelled “If you really want a unique "hashing" of […], you should be using an existing implementation of HMAC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code”

Comment: Well, no. If you want an unique, pseuduorandom 2^128 items long cycle you could use a reversible encryption/decryption algorithm (AES or other) that guarantees bijection on your 128 bit increasing ID. If you just want something which can collide every now and then, use HMAC.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see the cycle. You seem to be suggesting to use a block cypher to obtain a random permutation of numbers between 0 and 2^128-1. This is great if what you need is a permutation, but this permutation has very little chance of being a 2^128-cycle.

Comment: You're right, there's no cycle. You can reset the number being encrypted any time you want.